# Android: Search using custom searchview

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I implemented search method following [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/) tutorial. The search function and suggestions work fine. But the problem is when I call onSearchRequested() the following searchView appears

[image: first ss]

I can search here and get suggestion no problem

[image: second ss]

But I want to search on the searchView I added separately on my FragmentActivity

[image: final ss]

I want users to type here and show suggestion here. How do I achieve that?
My main activity is as follows

```
<activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Points to searchable activity -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".MapsActivity" />

        <!-- Points to searchable meta data -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

Comment: see `setOnQueryTextListener(SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since I did not get a proper answer, I had to find the solution on my own. After 2 days of googling and trial and error I found that I don't need to call `onSearchRequested()` on newer versions of Android. Instead if I have a `SearchView` I need to add the following lines

```
    mapSearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.msearchView); //msearchView is my SearchView name
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mapSearch.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Hope this will help anyone having this problem in future